# How can I suspend updates for my view while adding data to the model?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am using a 3rd party chart component. This component is divided in 2 parts:

A *chart UI Component* and a *dataseries* object that is bound to the charts dataseries property. To this data object I can add new points which are then rendered on the chart. Thats the way it is described in the documentation and it leaves me the possibility to add new points inside my ViewModel and even on a non-UI thread. It works very well and I have my View separated from my ViewModel.

Now my problem. As a tip for performance it is recommended to call the add for new data (especially several data) the following way:

```
using (graph.SuspendUpdate)
{
    dataseries.Add(manyPointsList);
}
```

But I don't have the graph inside the ViewModel. Are there any possibilities from WPF or an existing MVVM pattern to handle this?

I have seen (couldn't find the post again):

```
using (Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.DisableProcessing())
{
    dataseries.Add(manyPointslist);
}
```

but is this really equivalent?
And wouldn't I make the assumption it is WPF? My ViewModel could be used in WinForms (in theory) and I thought the goal of MVVM is to not have View specifics in ViewModel (although disabling rendering can be seen as UI specific as well).

Any thoughts on this or solution proposals?

Comment: _"I don't have the graph inside the ViewModel"_ -- what _do_ you have in your view model? How does your view model connect with your chart component and your data series? What part of your code _does_ know about the chart object (which I presume is the `graph` object that exposes `SuspendUpdate`)? As asked, there are far too many possible answers (see "too broad"), but by providing more specifics you may be able to redeem the question.

Comment: One other thing: I suggest you do it "the wrong way" first, just to make sure that you _will_ in fact get a significant performance improvement. There's no point in pursuing a more MVVM-friendly design (which can sometimes be a headache) unless you know for sure the effort will have the results you want.

Comment: Thanks for you comments. I am going for the "wrong way" and I agree with you that it is an accetable approach here. I wanted to know what other possibilties would exist. Maybes someone had the sam question. To your first comment: In my viewModel I have the dataseries. It is bound to the graph control via binding in xaml. By changing the dataseries the control updates. I understand it is a bit broad so I have provided 2 ways someone could dismiss or think they are good.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Thinking about your comment "too broad" a second time I cannot really agree. The question is, in its essence, quite narrow: How to call a UI components SuspendUpdate in ViewModel without violating MVVM. I believe there can't be too many options as scanning the internet and stackoverflow does not bring up much for my clarification.

Comment: Everyone's welcome to their opinion. That's why we have voting on SO. That said, given that your question includes essentially no real code example, your assertion that the question is not "too broad" is the same as saying that if anyone is able to come up with _some_ solution that is valid, that that solution is the _only_ solution possible. Given how flexible computers and human approaches to problem solving are, I take as given that simply can't be true. YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [Behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff725476%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) for that:

```
public class SuspendBehavior : Behavior<THE_TYPE_OF_YOUR_CHART/GRAPH>
{
    private IDisposable disposable;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SuspendUpdateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SuspendUpdate", typeof(bool), typeof(SuspendBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), OnSuspendUpdateChanged));

    public bool SuspendUpdate
    {
        get { return (bool) GetValue(SuspendUpdateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SuspendUpdateProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnSuspendUpdateChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var behavior = d as SuspendBehavior;

        var value = (bool) e.NewValue;
        if (value)
        {
            // AssociatedObject would be your graph
            behavior.disposable = behavior.AssociatedObject.SuspendUpdate ...
        }
        else
        {
            if (behavior.disposable != null)
                behavior.disposable.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Attach the behavior to your chart or graph

```
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:SuspendBehavior SuspendUpdate="{Binding ShouldSuspend}"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

and add `ShouldSuspend` bool property to your viewModel which will be set when you add new points

```
ShouldSuspend = true;
dataseries.Add(manyPointsList);
ShouldSuspend = false;
```

This will require you to add a reference to `System.Windows.Interactivity`.

although *Behaviors* is a concept in WPF it will only act as a code behind in your *View* which keeps your *ViewModel* clean from any references to UI elements directly.

Comment: does "disposable" need to be static? Otherwise I get an error for the OnSuspendUpdateChanged because it uses disposable object.

Comment: @Uwe do you get an error when you access it through the `behavior` variable? I've updated my example ...

Comment: I found the problem. In "if (value) { disposable" has to be "behavior.disposable".